# MVVM datagrid doesn't display

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Hi Learning MVVM and I am bit confused, I am trying to display my model name in a list and here what I have.

Model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace Morza.Model
{
    public class DBEnvironment : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private String _Name;
        private String _HostName;
        private String _HostPath;

        public DBEnvironment(String __name, String __hostname, String __hostpath)
        {
            Name = __name;
            HostName = __hostname;
            HostPath = __hostpath;
        }

        public String Name {
            get
            {
                return _Name;
            }
            set 
            {
                _Name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }

        public String HostName
        {
            get
            {
                return _HostName;
            }
            set
            {
                _HostName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("HostName");
            }
        }

        public String HostPath
        {
            get
            {
                return _HostPath;
            }
            set
            {
                _HostPath = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("HostPath");
            }
        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

ModelView

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Morza.Model;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace Morza.ViewModel
{
    internal class LoginViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {

        ObservableCollection<DBEnvironment> _DBEnvironments;

        private DBEnvironment _obj;

        public LoginViewModel()
        {
            DBEnvironmentInfo = new ObservableCollection<DBEnvironment>();
            DBEnvironmentInfo.Add(new DBEnvironment("T2", "127.0.0.1", "C:"));
            DBEnvironmentInfo.Add(new DBEnvironment("T2", "127.0.0.1", "C:"));
            DBEnvironmentInfo.Add(new DBEnvironment("T2", "127.0.0.1", "C:"));
            DBEnvironmentInfo.Add(new DBEnvironment("T2", "127.0.0.1", "C:"));
        }

        public DBEnvironment DBEnvironment {
            get
            {
                return _obj;
            }
            set
            {
                _obj = value;
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<DBEnvironment> DBEnvironmentInfo
        {
            get
            {
                return _DBEnvironments;
            }
            set
            {
                _DBEnvironments = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("PersonsInfo");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

View

```
<Window x:Class="Morza.View.Login"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Login" Height="260" Width="425" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Background="LightBlue" ResizeMode="NoResize">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="10"></RowDefinition> <!-- 0 Nothing -->
            <RowDefinition Height="25"></RowDefinition> <!-- 1 Label Instruction -->
            <RowDefinition Height="10"></RowDefinition> <!-- 2 Nothing -->
            <RowDefinition Height="25"></RowDefinition> <!-- 3 Username -->
            <RowDefinition Height="10"></RowDefinition> <!-- 4 Nothing -->
            <RowDefinition Height="25"></RowDefinition> <!-- 5 Password -->
            <RowDefinition Height="10"></RowDefinition> <!-- 6 Nothing -->
            <RowDefinition Height="25"></RowDefinition> <!-- 7 Environment -->
            <RowDefinition Height="10"></RowDefinition> <!-- 8 Nothing -->
            <RowDefinition Height="25"></RowDefinition> <!-- 9 Label Warning -->
            <RowDefinition Height="10"></RowDefinition> <!-- 10 Nothing -->
            <RowDefinition Height="25"></RowDefinition> <!-- 11 Button-->
            <RowDefinition Height="10"></RowDefinition> <!-- 12 Nothing -->
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="150"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="25"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="150"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Label Name="lblInstruction" Content="Enter a Username, Password, and Environment" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></Label>

        <Label Name="lblUsername" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Content="Username:" HorizontalAlignment="Right"></Label>
        <TextBox Name="txtUsername" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="3"></TextBox>

        <Label Name="lblPassword" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5" Content="Password:" HorizontalAlignment="Right"></Label>
        <PasswordBox Name="pwdPassword"  Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="5"></PasswordBox>

        <Label Name="lblEnv" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="7" Content="Environment:" HorizontalAlignment="Right"></Label>
        <ListView Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="7" ItemsSource="{Binding DBEnvironmentInfo}" >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Label Content="{Binding DBEnvironmentInfo.Name}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

        <Label Name="lblWarning" Content="" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Foreground="Red" Grid.Row="9" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></Label>

        <Button Name="btnLogin" Content="Login" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="11"></Button>
        <Button Name="btnCancel" Content="Exit" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="11" IsCancel="True"></Button>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

When running this code, the issue is the grid is blank. I am not using any framework that I am aware and don't really want to. If there something I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to set the DataContext of the Window:

```
<Window 
   ...
   xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:Morza.ViewModel">
   <Window.DataContext>
      <ViewModels:LoginViewModel />
   </Window.DataContext>
   ...
```

Also, another thing to mention is that you do not need to add the property name in your ListView DataTemplate:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Name}" />
```

This is because your DataTemplate is bound to a single object in the list.

Comment: I didn't add the datacontext on the xaml but on xaml.cs file sorry for this. Will edit my question to include this

Comment: In that case, the issue may just be your DataTemplate, please check my edited answer.

Comment: But by removing the DBEnvironmentInfo. it did the trick, you mention its because i have a single object? what if i want to property?

Comment: You are binding to the list, but your DataTemplate acts as a template for each item in the list. Therefore the DataContext of the DataTemplate is itself. I hope that made sense.